# Slow performance using std::distance to get std::map index

Tags: c++, dictionary, for-loop, iterator, distance

I have a std::map and I need all its key, value and index for some process.
My code works correctly. The only issue is: it's too slow.
Below is an example:

```
void run(const std::map <key, value>& myMap) {
    std::map <key, value>::const_iterator iter;
    for (iter = myMap.begin(); iter != myMap.end(); ++iter) {
        const auto& myKey = iter->first;
        const auto& myValue = iter->second;
        const auto index = std::distance(myMap.begin(), iter);
        // then some process here
    }
}
```

I use IgProf to profile the performance.

```
Rank    % total       Self       Self / Children   Function
[39]        8.2       9.06       0.69 / 8.37       run(const std::map <key, value>& myMap)
            5.6  .........       6.16 / 6.17         std::_Rb_tree_increment(std::_Rb_tree_node_base*) [clone .localalias.2] [54]
            1.4  .........       1.50 / 1.50         some process here [175]
            0.3  .........       0.36 / 0.36         std::_Rb_tree_increment(std::_Rb_tree_node_base const*) [428] 
            0.3  .........       0.34 / 0.83         _init [232]
```

Here `std::_Rb_tree_increment` costs too much time.
In this example code, I can manually calculate the index:
replacing `const auto index = std::distance(myMap.begin(), iter);` by `++index;`
I got a much faster performance

```
Rank    % total       Self       Self / Children   Function
[148]       2.3       2.42       0.60 / 1.81       run(const std::map <key, value>& myMap)
            1.7  .........       1.77 / 1.77         some process here [165]
            0.0  .........       0.03 / 0.04         std::_Rb_tree_increment(std::_Rb_tree_node_base*) [clone .localalias.2] [1268]
            0.0  .........       0.01 / 0.37         _init [420]
```

But in reality, I do need `std::distance` or something equivalent to get the index.
So I would really appreciate it if you could help me understand the reason of its slow performance.
Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`std::map` is a tree structure.  It's not random access, and elements don't have indices, and the only way to advance through the tree is to follow the links, one at a time.  Because of this, `std::map::iterator` is a BidirectionalIterator.  That means it only supports increment and decrement operations.  It doesn't support any sort of difference operation.  To get the difference between two of them you have to repeatedly increment the start iterator until it's equal to the end iterator.  Something like this:

```
template <typename Iterator>
size_t distance(Iterator start, Iterator end)
{
    size_t dist = 0;
    while (start != end) {
        ++dist;
        ++start;
    }
    return dist;
}
```

Looking at that function, you can probably see why your loop is slow.  Every time through the loop, `std::distance` has to walk through the tree and count how far from the beginning it is.  If you really need an index to go with your map, you'll need to maintain it yourself.  `std::map` doesn't seem like the right structure in that case though, since the indices will change as new elements are added.

Answer (score 3):

The for-loop is `myMap.size()` iterations. `std::distance(myMap.begin(), iter);` is 0 -- `myMap.size() - 1` iterations. You get the complexity `O(myMap.size()²)`.

Back to the linear complexity `O(myMap.size())`:

```
void run(const std::map <key, value>& myMap) {
    std::map <key, value>::const_iterator iter;
    size_t index = 0;
    for (iter = myMap.begin(); iter != myMap.end(); ++iter; ++index) {
        const auto& myKey = iter->first;
        const auto& myValue = iter->second;
        // const auto index = std::distance(myMap.begin(), iter);
        // then some process here
    }
}
```

[`std::map` iterator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map) is [*`LegacyBidirectionalIterator`*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/BidirectionalIterator), that is not a random access iterator (index in your terms), and supports only `++a`, `a++`, `--a`, `a--` operations (not `a + index`, `a - index` in your terms).

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I know `std::distance()` is redundant in the above example (and also mentioned `++index` in the question). I would like to understand why `std::distance(myMap.begin(), iter)` requires iterations? I thought it was a simple subtraction between two "index" and had a time complexity of O(1)

Comment: Because `std::distance(myMap.begin(), iter)` is smth like `size_t distance = 0; while (iter != myMap.begin()) { iter--; distance++; }`, it is not O(1). `iter - myMap.begin()` is not available to *LegacyBidirectionalIterator*.

Answer (score 1):

The class template `std::map` has bi-directional iterators, but not random-access iterators. So the call of `std::distance()` traverses all iterators between the two specified.

But in your case, the call of `std::distance()` is entirely redundant. You could just declare a variable of the type `size_t` as an index and increment it in each iteration of the loop.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I know `std::distance()` is redundant in the above example (and also mentioned `++index` in the question). I would like to understand why `std::distance(myMap.begin(), iter)` requires iterations? I thought it was a simple subtraction between two "index" and had a time complexity of O(1)